# How to make use of old apples?

Tags: apples, apple-pie

I have many apples, but the insides are already brown. The outside is slightly soft, perhaps bruised. The inside appearance is the same as if you cut an apple and let it sit out for 1 hour, but this is the appearance immediately after cutting.

Can these still be used for apple sauce or apple pie or some other dish, with good results?

Comment: If the insides are already brown, I'd throw them (or compost them); maybe they could be used the same way bananas can be used when they turn brown ?

Answer (score 3):

The apples have shriveled slightly owing to dehydration.    When the apples dry out air is admitted through the core then the fruit will oxidise from the inside out.    I would not use these apples for eating.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit involved but you should be able to use these for (hard) Cider.

You will need a lot of apples and a press (you can hire them here in the UK, or buy them second hand).

[Example Recipe](http://www.motherearthnews.com/real-food/how-to-make-hard-cider-zmaz07onzgoe.aspx)